# Is there something similar to Java's checked exceptions in Ada language?

Tags: exception, ada, static-analysis

Java forces programmer to explicitly specify exceptions raised by methods or provide handlers for them. Is there something similar in Ada language?

Comment: I know Ada has it, but I have never programmed in it before so I could not tell you what they are called or how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ada does not have exception contracts.  The [ARG](http://www.ada-auth.org/arg.html) has considered it, and - so far - decided that it isn't worth the effort ([AI12-0017-1](http://www.ada-auth.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/ai12s/ai12-0017-1.txt?rev=1.4)).

I've seen some cases recently, where it looks like it would be worth the effort.

SPARK (a provable subset/superset of Ada) prevents exceptions completely, so that is an option, but it isn't always feasible to prove absence of all exceptions completely.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in Ada is to write a tool to do it for you, see ASIS and libadalang.